# Hdmi video output blank on Tablet

Tags: android, hdmi

My Android app plays videos within the app using a videoView. When connecting the tablet to a TV using HDMI, I am able to see my tablets screen on the TV.

Everything seems to be working fine, however in my app, my videoView is ONLY displayed on the TV. The tablet is just blank. Is there a way to force the videoView to play the video on both the TV and the tablet? I want both screens to be identical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HDMI out is not part of the Android SDK, and in many cases is not even really a part of the standard Android OS. Device manufacturers can do what they want in terms of what is shown on the tablet and what is shown on the TV. There is nothing on `VideoView` or `MediaPlayer` to control this behavior.

If you are targeting some specific piece of hardware, you can try contacting the manufacturer to see if they have some beyond-the-SDK way of controlling this.